# How to put IF Statement inside string?

Tags: php

How to put IF Statement inside string like this?

```
<?php echo
"<div class='portfolio-info'>
   <form id='imgtitle' class='kart' action='" . base_url() . "gallery/delete' method='post'>
      <input type = 'hidden' name='delete_file' value='$image' />

      //I want to put IF here
      <button type = 'submit' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='delete fa fa-trash fa-3x'></i></button>  
      //END here

    </form>
 </div>";
?>
```

Comment: What is this? It is definitely a syntax error without `echo`

Comment: I'm just put it a little. I just ask how to put IF lol.. There

Comment: remove `php` tags from head and tail. and try this - `<?php   if(statement) echo "<button>"; ?>`

Comment: My php codes are 40 rows.. I can't pass the explain section.. I don't know what to fill...  and @RohanKhude please take a look where I want to put the IF Statement.. I thought this is <?php?> important?

Comment: This DIV are one part. I can't remove the PHP tags

Comment: What is the `if` for? Just split your `echo`s - Echo first block, then have an `if` statement to `echo` A or B, then `echo` the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
<?php echo
"<div class='portfolio-info'>
   <form id='imgtitle' class='kart' action='" . base_url() . "gallery/delete' method='post'>
      <input type = 'hidden' name='delete_file' value='$image' />
";

if(expression)      //put IF here
{
    //put multiple statements if any
    echo "<button type = 'submit' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='delete fa fa-trash fa-3x'></i></button>  ";
}

echo "</form></div>";
?>
```

After this please understand 'How to use Embedding PHP with HTML'

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. It will be helpful to other users

Answer (score 0):

You could test your condition upfront and place the result in a variable.  If the condition fails, just put it equal to the empty string.  Here using the ternary operator for assignment.

```
<?php

$base_url  = '/';
$image     = "foo";
$condition = true;

$submit = $condition
    ? "<button type = 'submit' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='delete fa fa-trash fa-3x'></i></button>" 
    : '';

echo
"<div class='portfolio-info'>
   <form id='imgtitle' class='kart' action='${base_url}gallery/delete' method='post'>
      <input type = 'hidden' name='delete_file' value='$image' />
      $submit
    </form>
 </div>";
```

Alternatively you could concatenate strings and use the ternary operator.  But this can get messy.

```
<?php
echo
 "<div class='portfolio-info'>
   <form id='imgtitle' class='kart' action='${base_url}gallery/delete' method='post'>
      <input type = 'hidden' name='delete_file' value='$image' />
      " . ($condition ? "<button type = 'submit' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='delete fa fa-trash fa-3x'></i></button>" : ''). "
    </form>
 </div>";
```

You could do away with the brackets, using echo with commas:

```
<?php
echo
 "<div class='portfolio-info'>
   <form id='imgtitle' class='kart' action='${base_url}gallery/delete' method='post'>
      <input type = 'hidden' name='delete_file' value='$image' />",
      $condition ? "<button type = 'submit' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='delete fa fa-trash fa-3x'></i></button>" : '',
      "</form>
 </div>";
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this:

```
<?php
<div class='portfolio-info'>
   <form id='imgtitle' class='kart' action='" . base_url() . "gallery/delete' method='post'>
      <input type = 'hidden' name='delete_file' value='$image' />";?>
         <?php if($_SESSION['admin']==1):?>  
            <button type = 'submit' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='delete fa fa-trash fa-3x'></i></button>
          <?php endif; ?>
<?="</form>
</div>
?>
```

Comment: @Progrock like I said, my codes are 40 rows, and I thought the rest other than I posted was unnessecary to post.. I'm done with it. No errors :p

Comment: This  part itself wasn't actually my work that I should worked on, but as the leader of the project, it's is our job to get it done.